# Nuances between "врать" and "лгать"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> **Врать** не буду, ...
>
> **Лгать** не буду, ...

I wonder how these two synonyms are nuanced or if they are simply interchangeable in these two instances.

> **лгать** мне прямо в глаза
>
> **врать** мне прямо в глаза

Comment: there's a vulgar version of these two in case you're interested

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка By all means. :)

Comment: the verb ***пиздеть***, a cognate of ***пизда*** - cunt, sometimes replaced with an euphemism ***звиздеть***

Comment: well, if one is to look into slur, then he has to really dive into it. Because sometimes a change of a single sound radically changes the meaning. Even just moving a stress without changing sounds can drastically change meaning. In your case "пизд**ˋи**ть" would mean a very different thing than "п**ˋи**здить". So, my take is, do not introduce readers into such words lightly. They require their own separate dedicated lesson.

Comment: If we would fest upon related funny quirks, then perhaps it is worth mentioning that "врать" and "врач" are (at least etymologically) same-root words, and they both allegedly are derived from sorcery :-D

Comment: There's no difference in meaning. "Лгать" feels somewhat outdated and pompous, I don't remember ever hearing it in an actual conversation.

Comment: An older discussion in Russian: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20149/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F

Comment: @Alex_ander now that is weird. Basically somehow people managed to create TWO Russian-language communities on StackExchange. I wonder was there some drama and intended split, or did it just happened, because someone failed to find the already existing one? I wonder if they can be merged now...

Comment: Ah, okay, I grokked it. This community is for foreigners mostly and that community for native speakers. Perhaps it would be nice if it was highlighted and cross-linked...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Значение у слов **врать** и **лгать** одинаковое, но **лгать** - литературное слово, а **врать** - разговорное, более грубое. Смысловых различий у слов **врать** и **лгать** нет.

The words **лгать** and **врать** have the same meaning, but **лгать** is a literary word, while **врать** is a rougher colloquial synonym. There are no semantic differences between these words.

Answer (score 9):

Врать is conversational, лгать is formal. "врать мне прямо в глаза" is an established colloquial expression and uses "врать". I googled "лгать мне прямо в глаза" and got two bad translations of romance pulps and a bad romantic pop song.

Note that the nouns, враньё and ложь, are less formal than the corresponding verbs. Ложь is neutral and can mean a calm "False." as well as an indignant "LIES!!!", враньё is a rough equivalent of "bullshit!"

Comment: in terms of usage ***bullshit*** is a bit stronger than ***враньё*** just because it's pejorative

Comment: My feeling is that "вра-ньё" is constructed as "action of lying", it is more of gerund than a noun. And since it is an action - it implies an actor. While "ложь" is indeed just a false claim itself. Compare with "попада-ние" and even "расте-ние"

Answer (score 2):

This might help you— **врать** used to mean "to speak". The word **врач** is related to this--meaning "he who speaks, casts spells". врать also has other rarer meanings—

**врать 
несов. - врать, сов. - совра́ть; разг.**

1) (говорить неправду) lie, tell lies

2) тк. несов. уст. (пустословить) talk nonsense

3) (быть неточным) be wrong
часы́ врут — the clock [watch] is wrong

4) разг. (фальшивить) play a false note; (в пении) sing out of tune
••

врёшь! — ≈ it's a lie!, nonsense!

**лгать**

1) (сов. солга́ть) lie, tell lies

лгать кому́-л в глаза́ — lie to smb's face

2) (сов. налга́ть) (на вн.; клеветать) slander (d)

So **Врать** means to speak, sing, do something in a untrue way, whereas **лгать** means to do something with purpose, in order to mislead, trick etc. The origins of **лгать** are related to betrayal or treason.

Comment: What is the down vote for?--lol. This is exactly the difference in meaning.

Comment: the meaning of *быть неточным* is a useful addition

Answer (score 2):

На соседнем форуме тоже поднимал этот [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20149/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F) Если кратко. В современном языке только стилистическая **лгать** более возвышенное слово и ложь как правило серьёзнее, чем враньё. В остальном отличий почти нет.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some interesting comments on [nuances of враньё](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Citations:vranyo) in particular. They're from English speakers; an article by a native speaker gives a couple examples from her life in this [NYTimes article](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/10/23/magazine/from-russia-with-lies.html).

Comment: Please provide useful information in the answer itself. Links may break over time.  As for the statement in NYT that *"враньё"* is a special form of lying. This statement is a lie itself. There is nothing special about it.

Comment: @Curt etymologically врать means chanting spells. Just like врач - doctor in modern language - was some shaman, which cures people while babbling unintelligible something. So that NYT article is totally off the mark when it describes that pretending by acting out without spelling a word. That would be притворство but never враньё. NYT being just a NYT again....

Comment: Additionally, I don't know if the article author is indeed native speaker now. I don't know who that person exactly is, but just googling for the name I can sett for example one ELENA GOROKHOVA who left USSR for good in 1950-s or maybe 1960-s: http://elenagorokhova.com/elena-4/ and one E.G. more left Russia in 1999 researchgate.net/profile/Elena_Gorokhova so... How long would it take to once native speaker to remain so after casting that language environment past oneself is anyone guess.

Answer (score 0):

В школе учили что слово **ложь** по происхождению означает то что лежит поверх, или скрывает, истину. Аналогично англ. **lie**.
**Враньё** можно перевести **straight lie**.

"Врёте в глаза" - по-моему менее стилистически согласовано чем "лжёте в глаза".

Comment: could you please give reference to such etymology of ***ложь***.... ***врать в глаза*** is a perfectly mundane collocation, ***лгать в глаза*** on the other hand isn't very common

Comment: В школе так объясняли происхождение. По-моему и так понятно. Поищите в словаре. Насчет "врать/лгать в глаза", - сегодня нет разницы.

Comment: i asked specifically because i did a lookup and such etymology isn't attested for in dictionaries i checked, the difference between ***врать в глаза*** and ***лгать в глаза*** seems to be in frequency

Comment: edited my answer so it doesn't imply academic precision